# $M(x,y)\,dx+N(x,y)\,dy=0$ can always be converted to the form $dy/dx=F(y/x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm being asked to prove that all $M(x,y)\,dx+N(x,y)\,dy=0$ can always be converted to the form $dy/dx=F(y/x)$.

My guess is that I just have to manipulate and that's easy. But I have no clue what $F(y/x)$ means. I've searched on google and the closest thing I have found are “functional equations”.

Can anybody help me understand this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is not true. Take for example $M=x$ and $N=1$.

Comment: Equations that can be written in the $F\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)$ form are called homogeneous, which can easily be confused with the other type of homogeneous equations: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomogeneousOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html

Comment: Hmm. How could f=x^3+y^3 be written in the form F(y/x)?